# will-paginate broken with Rails 5.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Ever since upgrading to Rails 5.1, I get the following error when trying to paginate unfiltered (but not filtered) user table results:

[image: will-paginate error]

I use will-paginate 3.1.6 and Rails 5.1.0. I'm not even sure which line is causing the error; presumably it's the line

```
format.html { @members = @members.page(params[:page]); render }
```

because right above the error I see a database call asking for users with offset 25 limit 25.

I even tried creating an `empty?` method for the (standard ActiveRecord) `User` model, but that changes the error to a complaint that this is not a string.

Do I need to change the call to will_paginate? Do I need an earlier version of will_paginate? How to make it work with Rails 5.1?

EDIT: this is how @members gets populated:

```
@members = User.order("id DESC")
if current_user.admin_level < 8
    @members = @members.where("country = ?", current_user.country)
end
```

Comment: You seem to be passing one single instance of a User model to `will_paginate` where as it requires an ActiveRecord relation. Can you add your controller and view logic?

Comment: Could you add the entire controller method?

Comment: @abM I just added the code creating the ActiveRecord relation.

Comment: If you are not sure what is causing the error, it is quite possible you have not shown us the code that is causing the error. Please create an [executable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like Benj did for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54274368/712765). Maybe even [use his](https://github.com/randoum/as_bug) as a staring point.

Answer (score 1):

The error is most probably is in view where you pass a single instance of `User` to `page_entries_info` instead of collection (you did not provide the view and whole controller action, so it's hard to tell)

Executable example of error can look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "bundler/inline"

install = true
gemfile(install) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem "rails", "5.1.0"
  gem "will_paginate", '3.1.6'
  gem "sqlite3"
end

require "active_record"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "will_paginate"
require "logger"
require "rack/test"

# we are skipping initializers so include manually:
require 'will_paginate/active_record'
require 'will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :users, force: true do |t|
    t.string :country
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.per_page = 25
end

class TestApp < Rails::Application
  config.root = __dir__
  config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "cookie_store_key"
  secrets.secret_key_base = "secret_key_base"

  config.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = config.logger
  Rails.logger  = config.logger

  routes.draw{ get "/" => "members#index" }
end

class MembersController < ActionController::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def index    
    @members = User.order("id DESC")
    @members = @members.page(params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{
        # passing single instance instead of collection:
        render inline: "<%= page_entries_info(@members.first) %>"
      }
    end
  end
end

require "minitest/autorun"

class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def test_returns_success
    User.create!
    get "/?page=1"
    assert last_response.ok?
    puts last_response.body
  end

  private
    def app
      Rails.application
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change

```
@members = @members.page(params[:page])
```

to

```
@members = User.page(params[:page])
```

but of course it depends on what `@members` was set to. If you previously set @members to an array of `User`s based on some search criteria, you should not instantiate the `User` objects but instead leave the relation in `@members`.

Comment: See my post, now edited to include the code where members gets populated.

Comment: @Sprachprofi you also need to post the relevant part of your view template so we can see how `@members` is being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line you think is causing the issue from this (in your controller):

`format.html { @members = @members.page(params[:page]); render }`

To this (if you're using JavaScript as well):

```
@members = Member.paginate(page: params[:page]).order("id DESC")
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

Or this (if you are would rather use the original):

`format.html { @members = Member.paginate(page: params[:page]); render }`

And in your view, try something like this:

```
<% if current_user.admin_level < 8 %>
  <%= will_paginate @members.where("country = ?", current_user.country) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

it's probably not the case, but [I've been reading the gem in question](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate#basic-will_paginate-use) and, shouldn't it be...?:

```
format.html { @members = @members.paginate(page: params[:page]); render }
```

Comment: `page` is correct. See your link under "New in Active Record 3" or [the wiki](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation).