# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_mtime after feature tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activestorage

When running feature Rspecs, I receive the following error (full trace at the bottom of this message)

#### Puma output

```
Rack app error handling request { GET /rails/active_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--db9451afdc95b292aa6a77c40e00ab0ceb687766/image.png }
#<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_mtime - /path/to/rails/app/tmp/storage/va/ri/variants/Gpu41CMPPeKLiMbfpzYYyCp5/110e017d16925dc7c50728c9c154a420079aa6e5fcc435db3e6e97b1380ecec8>
(followed by the full trace at the end of this message)
```

#### Rspec outpout

```
Failure/Error: last_modified = ::File.mtime(path).httpdate

Errno::ENOENT:
No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_mtime - /path/to/rails/app/tmp/storage/va/ri/variants/Gpu41CMPPeKLiMbfpzYYyCp5/110e017d16925dc7c50728c9c154a420079aa6e5fcc435db3e6e97b1380ecec8
(followed by the full trace at the end of this message)
```

#### Context

`product.image` is an ActiveStorage attachment. During the test the "products/_form" partial is rendered and is displaying the attachment file (namely a png image) with the following code: `= image_tag url_for(product.image.variant(resize: "120x120"))`. If I comment out this line, the error does not occur anymore.

The test itself succeed every times, the error seems to be triggered after the test. I verified all my `after` blocks, it seems to happen after all my after blocks.

The trace indicates that `ActiveStorage::DiskController.serve_file` triggers the errors. Is it that ActiveStorage app is not shutting down gracefully ?

I'm using `active_storage.service = :test` configuration, but `:file` gives the same errors.

#### Image broken

While a test fail, I can see in the "remote controlled" browser that the image is not display and there is a broken image icon instead.

#### Running the tests

There is a group of 4 featured tests that are going through the render of the  "products/_form" partial. When I run the 4 tests in a random order the error occurs randomly. Sometime I can see the error 2 times, sometimes 3 times.

when I run the tests individually the error does never appear.

#### How I attach the image

This is the helper I use to attach the file to the model before going through the test :

```
path = Rails.root.join 'spec', 'support', 'fixtures', 'img1.png'
raise 'Image does not exist' unless File.exist? path

product.image.attach io: File.open(path), filename: 'image.png'
```

I also tried to use this helper :

```
path = Rails.root.join 'spec', 'support', 'fixtures', 'img1.png'
raise 'Image does not exist' unless File.exist? path

blob =  ActiveStorage::Blob.create_after_upload! io: path.open, \
  filename: 'img1.png', content_type: 'image/png'
product.images.attach blob
```

And this helper :

```
path = Rails.root.join 'spec', 'support', 'fixtures', 'img1.png'
raise 'Image does not exist' unless File.exist? path

byte_size = path.size
checksum = Digest::MD5.file(path).base64digest

blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload!(filename: 'img1.png', \
   byte_size: byte_size, checksum: checksum, content_type: 'image/png').tap do |blob|
  ActiveStorage::Blob.service.upload(blob.key, path.open)
end

product.images.attach blob
```

#### System configuration

**Rails version**: 5.2.2

**Ruby version**: ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]

**Rbenv version**: rbenv 1.1.1-39-g59785f6

**Rspec related versions**: rspec 3.8.0 - capybara 3.12.0 - selenium-webdriver 3.141.0

#### Full trace

```
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/file.rb:63:in `mtime'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/file.rb:63:in `serving'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb:42:in `serve_file'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb:12:in `show'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.2.2/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:68:in `block in call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `each'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.12.0/lib/capybara/server/middleware.rb:48:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
     # /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
     # 
     #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
     #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
     #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Capybara::CapybaraError:
     #   Your application server raised an error - It has been raised in your test code because Capybara.raise_server_errors == true
     #   /opt/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.12.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:147:in `raise_server_error!'
```

#### Update

(Sorry for being silent, I had an emergency to attend to)

Here is an interesting information. I inserted after [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cd52ddd4ed2ab01bc5bb782ff108f32024bd9dfa/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb#L41), this code: `puts "SERVING #{path} - Exist ? #{File.exist? path}"`

And here is the output (observe the files names and the boolean value at the end of each line):

```
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/Me/GK/MeGKkqgbb7Sg4RbPoCYWR6pZ - Exist ? true
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/sG/3v/sG3vd2viGWmaf69pNXSChZPa - Exist ? true
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/fy/2C/fy2C8PpaR96YgCzwt5WVBLrQ - Exist ? true
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/sG/3v/sG3vd2viGWmaf69pNXSChZPa - Exist ? true
. (green dot)
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/Me/GK/MeGKkqgbb7Sg4RbPoCYWR6pZ - Exist ? false
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/sG/3v/sG3vd2viGWmaf69pNXSChZPa - Exist ? false
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/Me/GK/MeGKkqgbb7Sg4RbPoCYWR6pZ - Exist ? false
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/fy/2C/fy2C8PpaR96YgCzwt5WVBLrQ - Exist ? false
F (red F)
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/Me/GK/MeGKkqgbb7Sg4RbPoCYWR6pZ - Exist ? false
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/sG/3v/sG3vd2viGWmaf69pNXSChZPa - Exist ? false
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/Me/GK/MeGKkqgbb7Sg4RbPoCYWR6pZ - Exist ? false
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/fy/2C/fy2C8PpaR96YgCzwt5WVBLrQ - Exist ? false
F (red F)
SERVING /tmp/active_storage_tests20190129-10797-1rebdf7/Tx/DL/TxDLPEk3ykf8ETkURY5YZPgY - Exist ? true
```

As we can see the files path are the same, even between tests. Tough the database is cleaned between each tests. So there is "somewhere" where the file checksum is kept, for activestorage to reuse the same blob record. As a result it reuse the same file path and that's the reason why I have a FileNotFound error.

Any idea ? Please note that, additionally to DatabaseCleaner, I have an after block defined like this :

```
config.after(:each) do
  ActiveStorage::Current.reset
  ActiveStorage::Attachment.all.each(&:delete)
  ActiveStorage::Blob.all.each(&:delete)
end
```

#### I suspect a bug

Filled a PR with an application to reproduce https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34989

Waiting for them response

Comment: My guess is that file, image in your case, is not found.  Did you check if the file references are valid?

Comment: @tukan Actually the test itself succeed, meaning the file exists during the test. The errors occurs after the test

Comment: Isolate which test does that. Then, I'd suggest making a breakpoint at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3f0c7c5580e67120b2a42552c3624b4e552aa721/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb#L12 to see why it returns a path that doesn't exist a few commands later.

Comment: Seeing the error reported AFTER the tests does not mean it really happens after the tests. If you isolate the problematic single test case, paste it here as a part of your question and I think we might be able to help more.

Comment: The fact that the test passes makes me think that maybe there's something that happens during the test teardown process that is breaking. Could be worth throwing a debugger in the Rack gem source before [this line](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/file.rb#L65) and inspecting the path of the missing file. Clearly your issue is that it's looking for a file that is missing. Why it's missing, I'm not sure.

Comment: @tukan Yes, the file ref are valid. I also debugged with `File.exist? ActiveStorage::Blob.service.path_for(image.blob.key)`

Comment: @JanMinárik The problematic test is coming randomly, 2 or 3 out of the 4 tests running. And when I run them individually I never get the error. Puzzling

Comment: @Benj maybe some synchronization issue?  e.g. tests are running too fast?

Comment: @tukan I'm using inline queue adapter for active job, if this is what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the test passes just means that the test does not depend on that image being found. A broken image link will not generally cause a test to fail and it is in fact often the case that test writers do not even bother to supply mock images because it is (perceived to be) too much work and not relevant to the thing being tested.

See folks, this is why we [ask for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Now that the OP has [posted an example](https://github.com/randoum/as_bug), we can see that his problem is browser caching, and will be solved by replacing

```
product.images.attach io: File.open(path), filename: 'image.png'
```

with

```
product.images.attach io: File.open(path), filename: "image-#{Time.now.strftime("%s%L")}.png"
```

in the helper that does the attachment. I would not have solved this without having the example.

#### Explanation

ActiveStorage handles saving and serving files. OP was saving and serving images with it, which is definitely what it was intended for. In order to allow for different services to serve files in different ways, ActiveStorage separates the published URL from the actual image serving URL.

The published URL is almost a permalink: it is an encoded version of the database key for the attachment. ActiveStorage processes a request for the URL by looking up where the file is stored and sending a 302 temporary redirect to the URL that can be used to access the file, called a "service URL". When using AWS S3 to store files, the service URL can be a signed URL that expires quickly but nevertheless connects the browser directly to S3 rather than having to go through the web server as intermediary.

By default, the service URL is good for 5 minutes, and ActiveRecord explicitly sets

```
Cache-Control: max-age=300, private
```

on the 302 redirect. The browser caches this redirect response and for the next 5 minutes the browser will not even attempt to use or verify the published URL, it will immediately replace the public URL with the cached service URL.

Unfortunately, while the public URL is predictably recreated, the service URL is randomly generated, so when the browser does its automatic redirection, the previously valid service URL no longer works. The solution (or workaround, depending on your point of view) is to distinguish the public URLs by including a timestamp in the filename, so that tests will not reuse public URLs.

**Sidenote**

By the way, you should not be using `url_for` with `image_tag`. Change your ERB from

```
= image_tag url_for(product.image.variant(resize: "120x120"))
```

to

```
= image_tag(product.image.variant(resize: "120x120"))
```

Rails is smart enough to handle either case, but the latter way is the recommended way.

Comment: Thanks to your response, I ran the tests without headless, and noticed that the image is not displayed (with a broken image logo instead) before the error triggers. I added few details in my original message if you wan to have a look

Comment: It's an ActiveStorage attachment. I should have mention it

Comment: @Benj I added some other possibilities as well as some questions for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I updated my original message with the helpers I'm using. The image is attached in a `before` block, just after few `let!` blocks to create the records. Then the cleaning is done by DatabaseCleaner. Also I tried (with no luck) in an `after(:each)` to have `ActiveStorage::Current.reset; ActiveStorage::Attachment.all.each(&:delete); ActiveStorage::Blob.all.each(&:delete)`

Comment: `image_tag url_for(...)` and `image_tag(...)` are giving the same results

Comment: @Benj I believe I fixed your problem, and it has to do with browser caching.

Comment: Yep that's exactly it, I'm working on a PR to disable browser caching during test, and I'll submit it to rails team.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help and being so active. Sadly I did mark your answer valid too late. I'm asking the moderators to give you the rep points, and hope they'll do it. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Something is likely off with how you're setting up the image that you're testing against.  You might want to update that to how the Rails team handles it in their own tests:

```
module ActiveStorageHelpers
  # ported from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activestorage/test/test_helper.rb#L57
  def create_file_blob(filename: "image.jpg", content_type: "image/jpeg", metadata: nil)
    ActiveStorage::Blob.create_after_upload! io: file_fixture(filename).open, filename: filename, content_type: content_type, metadata: metadata
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ActiveStorageHelpers
end
```

Then place a tiny image file in `spec/fixtures/file/images.jpg` (that's where the `file_fixture` method will look for it).

With that in place, you can setup the image on your model in your feature test with something like:

```
instance_of_model.images.attach(create_file_blob)
```

Comment: I'm using a helper to attach the attachment to my model, it's purely based on [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried with `ActiveStorage::Blob.create_after_upload!` or `ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload!` exactly the same way the tests. No luck

Comment: Can you please see my edit (at the end of the original message)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with the exception happens after the test?

Test should be usually atomic and independent, so all resources you create should be removed immediately after your test finished.
Also tests are running in random order, so tests which rely on each other will fail sometimes - and sometimes not, depending on the run order.

Can you share the output or tests which fail?

Comment: The exception happens after the test meaning that I check all my `after` blocks, and the exception is triggered after the last one of them. My tests are isolated to each other, DatabaseCleanup is taking care of cleaning database between tests, there is no usage of instance variable in my tests, nor class instance variable in any of my code.