# Sessions not persisting in Rails 5.2 integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, integration-testing, minitest, warden

I have a multi-tenant app that uses Apartment for postgreSQL schemas and Devise for user authentication. Everything is running smoothly until I attempt to write some integration tests.

Here is a stripped down version of what I have so far (feel free to ask for more information):

```
# test/support/sign_in_helper.rb
module SignInHelper
  def sign_in_as(name)
    sign_in users(name)
  end
end


# test/test_helper.rb
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

#...

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  include SignInHelper
end


# test/system/article/post_test.rb
require "application_system_test_case"

class Article::PostTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test 'post a new document' do
    sign_in_as :will
    visit articles_path

    click_on 'Add New Article' # redirected to login page after clicking this button
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Hello world!'
    fill_in 'Content', with: 'Yes yes'

    click_on 'Create Article'
    assert_select 'h1', /Hello world!/
  end
end
```

The `articles_path` requires an authenticated user, so I know the sign in helper works. Yet whenever I attempt to go to another link, suddenly the user is unauthenticated.

I monkey patched Devise's `authenticate_user!` method like so:

```
def authenticate_user!(*args)
  byebug
  super
end
```

and confirmed that `warden.authenticated?` returned `true` for the `articles_path` but `false` while subsequently attempting to navigate to the `new_article_path`.

I have noticed this behavior in both integration test types, controller and system. However, this is not an issue when using this app in the development environment.

The most frustrating part, is that I have a different app that seems to have an identical setup to this app, but this authentication issue does not occur while testing.

How can I go about debugging this issue?

**System**

- Rails: 5.2.2
- Devise: 4.5.0
- Capybara: 3.13.2

---

**Update 1 (04 February 2019)**

Here is the Articles controller as requested by @BKSpurgeon

```
# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :archive]

  def index
    @articles = Article.where(archived: false)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article, notice: 'Your article was successfully created.'
    else
      flash[:error] = @article.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to articles_path, notice: 'Your article was successfully updated.'
    else
      flash[:error] = @article.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def archive
    if @article.archive!
      redirect_to articles_path, notice: 'Your article was successfully archived.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:name, :content, :archived)
    end
end
```

---

**Update 2 (04 February 2019)**

I wrote simple middleware and placed it before Warden to debug:

```
# lib/debug_warden_middleware.rb
class DebugWardenMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
    if env['warden'].present?
      puts "User (#{env['warden'].user.present?}), Class: #{@response.class.name}"
    end
    return [@status, @headers, @response]
  end
end

# config/application.rb
#...
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...

    config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, DebugWardenMiddleware
  end
end
```

And I noticed that warden seems to clear its user after every request, including requests for assets:

```
bin/rails test:system
Run options: --seed 39763

# Running:

Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 3.9.1 , codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:57466
User (true), Uri: ActionDispatch::Response::RackBody
User (false), Uri: Sprockets::Asset
User (false), Uri: Sprockets::Asset
User (false), Uri: Sprockets::Asset
User (false), Uri: ActionDispatch::Response::RackBody
User (false), Uri: ActionDispatch::Response::RackBody
User (false), Uri: Sprockets::Asset
[Screenshot]: tmp/screenshots/failures_test_post_a_new_article.png
E

Error:
Agenda::PostTest#test_post_a_new_article:
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "Name"
    test/system/article/post_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:PostTest>'


bin/rails test test/system/article/post_test.rb:4
```

As a side note, I am using both Sprockets and Webpacker.

Comment: paste in the articles controller. some ideas: (i) add in `<% byebug %>` in the `articles_path` view, and then see if you have a current user there - and if the user is logged in? (ii) check if the `new` action has been hit in the articles controller by again using `byebug` and again check if you have a `current_user` there. Then step through, line by line, seeing if you still have a current user. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @BKSpurgeon , I have updated the question with the ArticlesController. When inserting `<% byebug %>` into the index view, I found that a user _is_ logged in. However it never makes it to the `new` action, because it fails Devise's `before_action` `authenticate_user!`. This is why I assumed it has something to do with sessions not persisting in the test environment.

Comment: Try removing the monkey patch, and in your sign in helper, add a bybug statement and test whether the user is successfully signed in there?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would test if the user is signed in without the monkey patch. In the Integration test I don't have access to `current_user`, `warden`, or `env`.

Comment: see here: https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/56cdf362d78848b070daf1bd5bd3ba2e

Comment: Thanks for the example @BKSpurgeon. I have removed the monkey patch and inserted a `byebug`, but I'm not sure how I would check if the user signed in. Normally I would check this with `current_user`, `warden`, or `env`, but those aren't available in the context of `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`

Comment: i have updated the gist with further comments. important - is to remove the monkey patching before testing those things. perhaps in a git new branch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187941/discussion-between-will-and-bkspurgeon).

Comment: My guess would be there is something wrong with your setup that is causing the authentication cookie set via login to not be sent (or accepted) in future requests. Very difficult to debug without a working example. Take a look at https://github.com/randoum/as_bug which Benj created for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54274368/712765) for an example/starting point for creating a minimal example for debugging problems with RSpec on Rails and create something like that for us to dig into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I stumbled upon the answer after both [@BKSpurgeon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4880924/bkspurgeon) (in a chat message) and [@Old Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712765/old-pro) recommended I try to recreate the problem in a separate app to share with you all.

Because this app is multi-tenanted and using the Apartment gem, my testing setup was a little convoluted. Unfortunately, I did not include some of that setup, thinking it was irrelevant ([big mistake, huge!](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/399b1c2f-127f-4b30-ac56-0a04101054c3)). It wasn't until I tried to recreate my app that I notice the flaw. Here is my testing setup I was using:

```
# test/test_helper.rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'

# support files
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

# Apartment setup
Apartment::Tenant.drop('sample') rescue nil
Apartment::Tenant.create('sample') rescue nil
Apartment::Tenant.switch! 'sample'

# Capybara setup
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.default_host = 'http://lvh.me'
  config.always_include_port = true
end

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  include SubdomainHelper
  include SignInHelper # dependent on SubomainHelper

  setup do
    default_url_options[:host] = 'lvh.me'
    Apartment::Tenant.switch! 'public'
  end
end
```

...

```
# test/support/sign_in_helper.rb
module SignInHelper
  def sign_in_as(name)
    # This right here was the problem code
    user = users(name)
    use_account user.account
    sign_in user
  end
end
```

...

```
# test/support/subdomain_helper.rb
module SubdomainHelper
  def use_account(account)
    account.save unless account.persisted?

    default_url_options[:host] = "#{account.subdomain}.lvh.me"
    Capybara.app_host = "http://#{account.subdomain}.lvh.me"
    Apartment::Tenant.switch! account.subdomain
  end
end
```

...

```
# test/system/article/post_test.rb
require "application_system_test_case"

class Article::PostTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test 'post a new document' do
    sign_in_as :will
    visit articles_path

    click_on 'Add New Article' # redirected to login page after clicking this button
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Hello world!'
    fill_in 'Content', with: 'Yes yes'

    click_on 'Create Article'
    assert_select 'h1', /Hello world!/
  end
end
```

---

What ended up being the problem, was I was trying to grab the user in the `SignInHelper` before I had actually switched to the tenant containing that user. With that knowledge, I changed up my code to look like the following:

```
# test/support/sign_in_helper.rb
module SignInHelper
  def sign_in_as(name, account)
    use_account accounts(account)
    sign_in users(name)
  end
end
```

...

```
# test/system/article/post_test.rb
require "application_system_test_case"

class Article::PostTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test 'post a new document' do
    sign_in_as :will, :sample

    # ...
  end
end
```

And now the sessions are persisting. One thing that still confuses me is, why was I able to log in at all? I have chalked it up to lingering test data, but that is more of a guess than anything else.

Comment: glad you solved it. Your comment: "One thing that still confuses me is, why was I able to log in at all? I have chalked it up to lingering test data, but that is more of a guess than anything else."..........don't guess: try to find out why. if it is NOT lingering test data, then you will have a serious security breach!!