# Active_Storage (Failed to load resource: 500 error) in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using active_storage to store multiple photos for a model(Project).
In the inspector console I have a 500 Error, Failed to Load Resource.

### My Project.new form

```
<%= f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true } %>"
```

### My Controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, 
:destroy]

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      redirect_to project_path(@project)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update

    if @project.update(project_params)
      redirect_to project_path(@project)
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Didn\'t save'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

  private

 def project_params
    projectParams = params.require(:project).permit(:title, 
:description, :remove_image, :objective, :technology, :project_type, 
:url, :programming_language, components:[], images:[])
  end

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

### My Project Model

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images

  attr_accessor :remove_image

  after_save :purge_images, if: :remove_image
  private def purge_images
    images.purge_later
  end

end
```

This are my terminal errors

Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_mtime - /app/storage/S7/vk/S7vkBW2r7UitAHR33kSEqq3M):

2019-06-18T19:29:47.072176+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-06-18T19:29:47.072105 #4] FATAL -- : [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/file.rb:63:in `mtime'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072178+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/file.rb:63:in`serving'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072179+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2.1/app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb:42:in `serve_file'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072180+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.2.1/app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb:12:in`show'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072181+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072182+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in`process_action'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072183+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072184+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in`block in process_action'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072185+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072186+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in`process_action'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072187+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072188+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in`block in process_action'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072189+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072190+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in`instrument'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072191+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072192+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in`process_action'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072193+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
2019-06-18T19:29:47.072194+00:00 app[web.1]: [bf728315-012e-45f4-9d98-47ddb3ce2ffa] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in`process_action'
 ▸    Logs eventsource failed with: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: This looks similar to other cache issues

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34989 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274368/errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rb-file-s-mtime-after-feature-tests might be able to help

Comment: Thanks Mark, this ended up being a cloud storage problem with amazon