# How to move Active Storage data from one machine to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Because reasons we are trying to move a system from one machine to another one. It has several files in the `storage` directory. I rsynced it (using `-a`) to a local environment to see if everything works, but turns out not all the files are available, some of them raise an exception:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_mtime - /path/to/project/storage/as/df/asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf):
```

Of course I checked the routes and they exists. I've been reading a bit about how Active Storage works and I maybe the URLs are getting invalidated for some reason, but why some files work?  Why the exception mentions `mtime`? And more importantly, how can I do the migration smoothly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if this is the same issue as yours, but a similar issue was due to browser caching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274368/errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rb-file-s-mtime-after-feature-tests

Comment: is the file in question a newly uploaded one?(that's already in db and on old system, but was not synced yet?)

Comment: Hey folks, thanks for the input. Making sure that I could discard it I found the culprit: case-insensitivity vs case-sensitivity 

Comment: https://www.stefanwienert.de/blog/2018/11/05/active-storage-migrate-between-providers-from-local-to-amazon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is actually the filesystems + Active Record names  You can consider this a corner case: My local machine runs macOS, while the server runs Linux, so if I had folders `Vf` and `VF` on Linux, on macOS they become one (whichever is downloaded firs). Active Storage relies on case-sensitive filenames, and that's why some of the files work fine, but others are not found